# Withdraw paper after the conference

Tags: conference

It is possible to withdraw paper after conference is held but paper still not published in ieee xplore.

Answer (score 4):

The formal "point of no return" is the moment when you have submitted the copyright form. After this, you can still ask the conference chairs and the IEEE contact person to withdraw the paper. While you should not expect a positive reply, there's still a certain chance that they accommodate your request based on good will.

To improve your chances, you should reach out to them as soon as possible. Later in the publication process, the effort for performing the withdrawal may be greater, and you would also have wasted more time on their side to process your paper.

Comment: It has been 4 month passed. Is it possible to contact ieee contact person.

Comment: Pretty late, but not impossible. Contact them now.

Comment: How to write them?

Comment: A short e-mail, asking them if it's possible to withdraw your paper. You should state a reason. For example, you could say that the feedback during the conference made you aware of severe problems with the paper. Since you're not satisfied with quality of the paper anymore, you would like to improve it to resubmit at another conference. You should also keep the conference chairs in the conversation.